# c++: Copy ctor and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, copy

So, c++ generates an automatic copy ctor for classes. What what happens when the class containes pointers? We just tested this at my university, and to my confusion, we could copy objects containing pointers, and the pointers were split.

```
obj a;
a.push(20);
a.push(100);
obj b = a;
b.pop();
b.push(500);
```

a now a contains 20, 100 and b contains 20,500, even though the values (20,100,500) are stored in a linked list using pointers. How is that possible?

Comment: This will produce a shallow copy. The default copy constructor copy's pointers by value. So you have two pointers pointing to the same memory.

Comment: That's possible as it seems to be a stack implementation by seeing function names. You pushed 20 then 100 and then assigned a to b then you did a pop means you deleted 100 and the you pushed 500 in b so values should be what you have said.

Comment: Yes, class members are copied, and if those class members are pointers, that means the pointers are copied. How *else* should it work?!

Comment: Could you show the definition of `obj`?

Comment: apparently obj has a user-defined copy ctor which copies values

Comment: I wonder if your stack is implemented using array...remember after the default constructor the both object have same byte footprint..so if it is a array it will be duplicated when you pop B , A is not affected..

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are simple copyable values, and that is how a class's implicitly copy constructor treats them. This is sometimes referred to as a "shallow" copy since it does not copy the objects being pointed to.

If you want to attach "ownership" semantics to a pointer then you will have to do that yourself, by writing your own copy/move operations for the class containing it, or by using an existing smart pointer class to do that for you.

For example, in this case, you could use `unique_ptr` to prevent the nodes being copied from one list to another (while allowing them to be moved in and out of a list); or you could write your own copy-constructor and assignment operator to copy the nodes being pointed to, not just the pointer, to get "deep" copy semantics.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your underlying class.  If obj was derived from something which has a copy constructor (it looks like a std stack class or something), this one would do a good copy.  We'd probably need to see the whole code and where push/pop is coming from.